# Using multiple clients MQTTAsync independently

Tags: c++, multithreading, mqtt

I have a С++ program that needs several "MQTT" clients at the same time.
The problem is that only the last client created is working.

I am using paho.mqtt.c async.

Does paho.mqtt.c support more than one client per program?

Comment: Why do you think you need several clients? A single client can publish/subscribe to as many topics as needed.

Comment: Also edit the question to show your code

Comment: Several clients for several brokers.

Comment: I had a bug in my code that led to the generation of the same values from the std::rand. I used a random for the client id. The broker breaks the connections, leaving only unique identifiers. Now everything is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but client id must be unique per broker